# Does Lucida Sans Unicode font in Windows 7 have a bold style?

Tags: fonts, typography

I am trying to set an alternative to Mac Lucida Grande font with Lucida Sans Unicode for Windows users and found out that I see no bold style of it in my Windows 7. Is that common for all Windows 7? How about Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

> What we want to do is pick only the good traits: the normal face of
>   Lucida Sans Unicode, and the bold and italic variants of Lucida Sans.
>   The solution is to “create” a hybrid font set:
>
> ```
> body {
>     font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
> }
>
> strong, em, b, i {
>     font-family: "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
> }
> ```

-
 [Lucida Hybrid: The ‘Grande’ Alternative](http://www.brownbatterystudios.com/sixthings/2007/03/14/lucida-hybrid-the-grande-alternative/)